# Trouble with using overloaded << for std::variant

Tags: c++, c++17, perfect-forwarding, argument-dependent-lookup

I have an overloaded `<<` for an aliased `std::variant` (`A::Var`). I also have a templated function defined in a class in a different namespace `C::Wrapper` which just forwards its argument to an `std::ostream`.

I am trying to invoke it from another function defined within a class in `A`, `A::Foo`, but this is giving me compiler errors. This toy example is below.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <variant>

namespace C {
  struct Wrapper {
    template<typename T>
    auto& operator<<(T&& v) {
      std::cout << std::forward<T>(v);
      return *this;
    }
  };
}

namespace A {
  using Var = std::variant<bool, int>;

  auto& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const A::Var& v) {
    std::visit([&os](auto i) { os << i; }, v);
    return os;
  }

  struct Foo {
    void m() {
      C::Wrapper wrap;
      Var v{3};
      wrap << "hi"; // works
      wrap << v; // compiler error
    }
  };
}

int main() { 
  A::Foo a;
  a.m();
}
```

`g++ -std=c++17` gives the following error:

```
main.cpp: In instantiation of ‘auto& C::Wrapper::operator<<(T&&) [with T = std::variant<bool, int>&]’:
main.cpp:27:11:   required from here
main.cpp:8:15: error: no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘std::ostream’ {aka ‘std::basic_ostream<char>’} and ‘std::variant<bool, int>’)
    8 |     std::cout << std::forward<T>(v);

... many candidate functions none including my overloaded << for A::Var
```

I expected it to compile successfully and print `3` when run. I tried making all the definitions out of line, removing the `const` qualifier, making the overloaded `<<` global, but none of those worked.

How can I fix this error, while keeping the namespace and class structure?

---

*UPDATE*:

The code compiles with gcc by defining `<<` in the global namespace, like this, but it fails with clang:

```cpp
namespace A {
  using Var = std::variant<bool, int>;
}

auto &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const A::Var &v) {
  std::visit([&os](auto i) { os << i; }, v);
  return os;
}

namespace A {
  struct Foo {
    void m() {
      C::Wrapper wrap;
      A::Var v{3};
      wrap << "hi"; // works
      wrap << v;    // compiler error
    }
  };
} // namespace A
```

Error with `clang++ -std=c++17`:

```
main.cpp:7:15: error: call to function 'operator<<' that is neither visible in the template definition nor found by argument-dependent lookup
    std::cout << std::forward<T>(v);
              ^
main.cpp:28:10: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'C::Wrapper::operator<<<std::variant<bool, int> &>' requested here
    wrap << v;    // compiler error
         ^
main.cpp:17:7: note: 'operator<<' should be declared prior to the call site
auto &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const A::Var &v) {
      ^
1 error generated.
```

Why does it work with gcc, but not with clang?

Comment: `Var` is just an alias, not an independent type. You are invoking `C::Wrapper::operator<<(const std::variant<bool, int> &)`, and since you are not referring to `namespace A` anywhere in that call, ADL doesn't know to look for your overloaded `operator<<` in `namespace A`. It will only consider operators in `C::Wrapper` `namespace C`, and the global namespace.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I found that if I define the overloaded << for the variant in the global namespace, it works with gcc, but it fails with clang. This would be a fine solution, but I do need it to work with clang as well. Any idea why?

Comment: Not without seeing your updated code, and the actual error message.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I updated the question with code and the error message

Comment: @Albert That GCC accepts the change in your edit is a bug that was fixed with GCC 12, see https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=51577. The only correct way to customize `<<` for `ostream`'s is to have an actual custom class `X` and a `operator<<` overload in the exact same namespace that `X` belongs to. Customization for `std::` types is impossible to do properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Argument-dependent lookup (ADL) doesn't consider namespaces associated with aliases. (That wouldn't make sense either. Should the compiler remember all namespaces having an alias to `std::variant<bool, int>` and then suddenly consider all functions declared there as belonging to `std::variant<bool, int>`?)

Make `Var` a proper independent type. Either you would make it a class with a private `std::variant<bool, int>` member and then you can implement and forward the parts of the interface of `std::variant` that you need, or you let `Var` inherit publicly from `std::variant<bool, int>` and inherit the constructors, which has the benefit that `std::visit` will still work out-of-the-box.

Then ADL will take into account `operator<<` overloads in the namespace `A` when you apply `<<` to a `Var`.